# Remove bootstrap media queries from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to remove just the boostrap media queries in my Rails app? I am unable to find the bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap styles are located in the gem installation directory.  You can find this directory by issuing the following command in your terminal and look for `GEM_PATH`:

```
gem env
```

Another way to find the gem path is by issuing

```
bundle show bootstrap
```

which will include the path of the gem installation.

Once you've located the path, copy the directory `bootstrap` from `GEM_PATH/vendor/assets/stylesheets/` to your `app/assets/stylesheets` directory.  I think the file you want to look at is `app/assets/bootstrap/responsive.scss`, at least this is where you want to start.  Depending upon what you want to modify, modify the the content of this file.